# Как обновить запись в БД с помощью CRUD операций?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Не могу написать функцию которая обновляет запись в БД. Пробую так:

```
public void Update(string name, int age, int id)
{
    using(VideoGamesDatabaseContext context = new VideoGamesDatabaseContext())
    {
        if(context.VideoGames != null)
        {
            var update = context.VideoGames.Where(r => r.Id == this.id);
            context.VideoGames.Update(update);
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а проблемы какие?

Comment: не могу написать функцию которая обновляет запись в БД

Comment: чтобы это сделать, надо 1) Получить запись из БД 2) Изменить её 3) Сохранить изменение в БД. Что из этого вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: я не могу изменить её

Comment: ну а что не получается то?

Comment: Я получил запись из БД , а потом я не знаю как её изменить

Comment: как бы вы её меняли, если бы вы она у вас уже была? Есть пример кода?

Comment: `var update = context.VideoGames.Where(r => r.Id == this.id).Single();`?

Comment: а что делает Single() ?

Comment: [Операции Single, SingleOrDefault, ElementAt и ElementAtOrDefault](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level3/3_6.php)

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
public void Update(string name, int age, int id)
{
    using (VideoGamesDatabaseContext context = new VideoGamesDatabaseContext())
    {
        var entity = context.VideoGames.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == this.id);
        if(entity != null)
        {
            entity.Age = age;
            entity.Name = name;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Это простой и надёжный подход. Когда вам надоест все поля выписывать постоянно - переходите на использование CurrentValues.SetValues

См. подробнее тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25894587/5752652

Comment: да да спасибо .